# Merge two rows with condition AWK

Tags: awk, printing, merge, uniq

I have question. I would like to merge two or three rows with condition into one row with specific printing.

INPUT: File has 6 row and tab delimited

```
LOL   h/h  2  a  b  c
LOLA  h/h  3  b  b  b
SERP  w/w  4  c  c  c 
DARD  s/s  5  d  d  d 
GIT   w/w  6  a  b  c
GIT   h/h  6  a  a  b
GIT   d/d  6  a  b  b
LOL   h/h  7  a  a  a
```

Output: there are 2 conditions: if (`$1`s are the same and `$3`s are the same) merge rows together with specific printing

```
LOL   h/h  2  a  b  c
LOLA  h/h  3  b  b  b
SERP  w/w  4  c  c  c 
DARD  s/s  5  d  d  d 
GIT   w/w  6  a  b  c h/h  6  a  a  b d/d  6  a  b  b
LOL   h/h  7  a  a  a
```

I have this code:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NF>1{a[$1] = a[$1]"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6};END{for(i in a){print i""a[i]}}'
```

But it is merging by 1st column only and I am not sure if it is good to use this code.

Comment: In the input, I see only one file ...can you add the second file

Comment: also can $1 be duplicate in a single file

Comment: Sorry, I would like to merge rows with this condition. I repaired it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '($1 FS $3) in a{k=$1 FS $3; $1=""; a[k]=a[k] $0;next} {a[$1 FS $3]=$0} END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
SERP  w/w  4  c  c  c
LOL   h/h  2  a  b  c
LOLA  h/h  3  b  b  b
DARD  s/s  5  d  d  d
LOL   h/h  7  a  a  a
GIT   w/w  6  a  b  c h/h 6 a a b d/d 6 a b b
```

Explained:

```
($1 FS $3) in a {  # if keys already seen in array a
    k=$1 FS $3
    $1=""           # remove $1
    a[k]=a[k] $0    # append to existing
    next
} 
{ a[$1 FS $3]=$0 }  # if keys not seen, see them
END { 
    for(i in a)     # for all stored keys 
        print a[i]  # print
}
```

Comment: Thanky you James and Jay

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer for gawk v4 which supports multi-dimensional array. One columns from first file are stored in a multi dimensional array, things are easy to compare with second file column. My solution show an example printf which you can modify as per your needs.

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

NR==FNR {          # for first file
    a[$1][0] = $2; # Store columns in
    a[$1][1] = $3; # multi dimensional
    a[$1][2] = $4; # array
    a[$1][3] = $5;
    a[$1][4] = $6;
    next;
}

$1 in a && $3 == a[$1][1] {
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $2, a[$1,0])
}
```

Comment: Really nice to get results by array

Answer (score 1):

Answer using gawk v3 where I cannot use multi-dimensional array

```
#!/bin/gawk -f

NR==FNR {
   a[$1]
   b[$1] = $2;
   c[$1] = $3;
   d[$1] = $4;
   e[$1] = $5;
   f[$1] = $6;
   next;
}

$1 in a && $3 == c[$1] {
    print $0
}
```

**One-liner**

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; b[$1] = $2; c[$1] = $3; d[$1] = $4; e[$1] = $5; f[$1] = $6; next; } $1 in a && $3 == c[$1] { print $0 }' /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
```